# Silverlight - RadTabControl Issue

Tags: silverlight

I am using Silverlight with Telerik Controls.

There is one scenarios where i stuck with it.

1) I have added Tab control into page(XAML page) with two tab Items.
2) I have also added stack panels into both tab items to dynamically add controls into respective stack panels.
3) Then Dynamically added combo boxes into stack panel and these combo boxes are binding with datasource. 
4) I am giving bydefault selection functionality for combo by coding, if label name and values of the datasource matching then it will bydefault select perticular item.
5) And finally when i click on the Map button then it will give me two objects with selected comboxes list with respective tabs.
6) When i directly click on the Map buttom then it is giving me proper result.
7) But i did some changes like select some of combo boxes and remove selection from combo boxes then it is givng me correct result of currently selected tab Item. and another tab item shows with zero selction.
8) In this case, i am not able to find controls from another tab.

Can anyone plz help me for a correct way...

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Have you posted this to the community forum or posted a support ticket concerning the issue you are having?  If possible, please submit a support ticket or post to the forum with the code showing what you are working on so we can look a bit more into the issues you are having.

Thanks!
Evan